# How to restrict users Routes in reactjs

Tags: reactjs, express, routes, react-hooks, next.js

How can i restrict users routes ?
I want to restrict users maually typing url in the address bar , for Eg: http://localhost:3000/admin if the user is in https://localhost/users.
I want only the admin to use the `/admin` route.

I'm trying to build multi user blog,
and for the route `/admin`,
i don't want normal users to maually type the route in address bar like http://localhost:3000/admin where the `/admin` route is only for admin ,
so whenever the user types manually in address bar as http://localhost:3000/admin
i want to display the error message and redirect the user back to root page.

I'm using `useEffect` of react and authenticating the user for normal user and admin and using `Router.push('/')` if the user is not admin and also want to display the page which says ENTRY RESTRICTED , the error message i am getting from the api by `res.json()`.
It is working but the the issue is the user is still able to see the admin dashboard for like 2/3 secs,
and then it is being redirected to the root page.
I want to restrict that and display the message.

REPO :

https://github.com/nitink66/blog-frontend

https://github.com/nitink66/blog-backend

I'm also trying to not push node_modules folder into github by adding `.gitignore` but for some reasons it is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For role based:

Follow [React Rolebased example](https://jasonwatmore.com/post/2019/02/01/react-role-based-authorization-tutorial-with-example). This might be help to you

Repo:

to ignore node_modules 
replace below code

```
/node_modules
```